# How to enable and disable a clang-tidy rule in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang-tidy

Visual Studio has a feature that lets me enable clang-tidy checks. In the property pages, I went to *Configuration properties*, *Code analysis*, *General* and set "Enable Clang-Tidy" to "Yes":

[image: Enable Clang Tidy]

In the *Clang-Tidy* section, Visual Studio allows me to enter Clang-Tidy rules:

[image: Property pages]

However, it says: "Enable or disable ...". How do I enable a check and how do I disable a check? That input box just takes a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checks are passed to the clang-tidy command line as is. This means:

1. You enable them by just using the string
2. You disable them by adding a `-` in front of the check
3. You separate multiple of them by comma
4. You can use wildcards like `clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-cplusplus*`

As mentioned on https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/:

> ```
> clang-tidy options:
>
> --checks=<string>       - Comma-separated list of globs with optional '-'
>                           prefix. Globs are processed in order of
>                           appearance in the list. Globs without '-'
>                           prefix add checks with matching names to the
>                           set, globs with the '-' prefix remove checks
>                           with matching names from the set of enabled
>                           checks. This option's value is appended to the
>                           value of the 'Checks' option in .clang-tidy
>                           file, if any.
> ```